# Array of strings populating inside secondary thread but primary thread shows array as null

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a secondary thread which receives (array of strings) data from the network and then stores those values in a `public String array` (which has been declared outside the secondary thread) like this:

```
//Code to fetch result in XML format
URL GetCardXmlUrl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/searchresultxml/search_xml_output.xml");
URLConnection GetresultXmlConnection = GetCardXmlUrl.openConnection();
InputStream ResultInstream = new BufferedInputStream(GetresultXmlConnection.getInputStream());
Serializer PhoneBookSerializer = new Persister();

Search_info_xml parse_result_xml = PhoneBookSerializer.read(Search_info_xml.class, ResultInstream);
SearchResult.this.mobile_nos = parse_result_xml.getPhones();

Log.d("note:", "getting stuff");
Log.d("number: ", mobile_nos[0]);
```

Here `mobile_no` is the public variable. `Log.d("number: ", mobile_nos[0]);` successfully displays the value.

But when I try to access the same array (after the secondary thread is done with it) from the main thread and try to populate a list from it, I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

Here is how I access my array:

```
try {
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.phonebook_listview, mobile_nos));

    } catch(Exception e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is how I have declared `mobile_nos` array: `public String[] mobile_nos = new String[20];`

Any idea what could be the problem? Or am I doing it wrong?

EDIT: Full code, as requested.

```
public class SearchResult extends ListActivity {

    public volatile String[] mobile_nos = new String[20];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //Get the search string sent by search.class via bundle
            Bundle valBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String searchString = valBundle.getString("search_string");
            Log.d("company: ", searchString);

            getSearchResult(searchString);

            try {

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.phonebook_listview, mobile_nos));
            } catch(Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the mobile number
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

`getSearchResult` method definition:

```
public void getSearchResult(final String searchString){

        /*--The connection to the server is established in another (not main) thread.
        This prevents the app to stop responding if the connection to the server is not established
        or it takes time to establish the connection--*/

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    //Send search string to the server
                    URL mobileurl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/project_server/Search");
                    URLConnection connection = mobileurl.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);

                    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                    out.write(searchString);
                    out.close();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    in.readLine();
                    in.close();

                    //Fetch result in XML format
                    URL GetCardXmlUrl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/searchresultxml/search_xml_output.xml");
                    URLConnection GetresultXmlConnection = GetCardXmlUrl.openConnection();
                    InputStream ResultInstream = new BufferedInputStream(GetresultXmlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Serializer PhoneBookSerializer = new Persister();

                    Search_info_xml parse_result_xml = PhoneBookSerializer.read(Search_info_xml.class, ResultInstream);
                    SearchResult.this.mobile_nos = parse_result_xml.getPhones();

                    Log.d("note:", "getting stuff");
                    Log.d("number: ", mobile_nos[0]);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

Comment: It's probably the common case. You might be creating two objects..

Comment: how do you know `the secondary thread is done with it` ?

Comment: @njk2 By `done with it` I meant that the thread has inserted the values into the array. 
@InderKumarRathore You mean that the secondary thread is creating a different instance of the variable?

Comment: Yeah may be...you have to sort it out that it is single object

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Any idea about how I can do that?

Comment: Either create a singleton to share data in you app or pass the same object from one class to another..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do:

```
getSearchResult(searchString);
try {
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.phonebook_listview, mobile_nos));
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In getSearchResult you start new Thread, and before it ends you run setListAdapter with mobile nos which is new String[20]. You forgot that Thread runs simultanously with rest of your code.

Try something like this:

```
public void getSearchResult(final String searchString){

        /*--The connection to the server is established in another (not main) thread.
        This prevents the app to stop responding if the connection to the server is not established
        or it takes time to establish the connection--*/

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    //Send search string to the server
                    URL mobileurl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/project_server/Search");
                    URLConnection connection = mobileurl.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);

                    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                    out.write(searchString);
                    out.close();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    in.readLine();
                    in.close();

                    //Fetch result in XML format
                    URL GetCardXmlUrl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/searchresultxml/search_xml_output.xml");
                    URLConnection GetresultXmlConnection = GetCardXmlUrl.openConnection();
                    InputStream ResultInstream = new BufferedInputStream(GetresultXmlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Serializer PhoneBookSerializer = new Persister();

                    Search_info_xml parse_result_xml = PhoneBookSerializer.read(Search_info_xml.class, ResultInstream);

                    final String[] data = parse_result_xml.getPhones();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchResult.this, R.layout.phonebook_listview, data));
                        }
                    });

                    Log.d("note:", "getting stuff");
                    Log.d("number: ", mobile_nos[0]);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

and remove

```
try {
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.phonebook_listview, mobile_nos));
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

after calling getSearchResult method. You can also remove mobile_nos field

Answer (score 0):

This is due to memory inconsistency error. Instead of global variable you should use synchronized getter or post your results to the UI thread after parsing xml.

Or you can declare mobile_nos as volatile.
You should also ensure that you got only one instance of mobile_nos and that you read it AFTER parsing for sure. But this is IMHO design issue.

Comment: I tried the UI thread method but the problem remained. Any idea what could be the best way for two threads to exchange data?

Comment: @Gaskoin - Can you demonstrate what you explained with a sample code?